# Laravel 5.4 eloquent relationship and local scope

Tags: laravel-5, relationship

I use laravel 5.4 and have 2 models, User and Provinces.

In model User:

```
    public function scopeWithSort($query, $sorting, $by)
    {
        return $query->orderBy($sorting, $by);
    }
    public function province()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Province', 'loction_id');
    }
```

In controller User:

```
$query = User::with('province')->select('*');
if ($request->sorting == 'location_id') {
   $query->withSort('provinces.name', $request->by); // ** error line
}
```

How can I sorting by using this relation. Thanks advances!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a different approach.

You can order the query with a modified `withCount()`:

```php
if ($request->sorting == 'location_id') {
    $query->withCount(['province' => function($query) {
        $query->select('name');
    }])->orderBy('province_count', $request->by);
}
```

Or you sort the query result:

```php
$users = $query->get();
if ($request->sorting == 'location_id') {
    $users = $users->sortBy('province.name', $request->by);
}
```

Comment: Thanks your reply! But why using `withCount()` ?
Besides i also use pagination, so if not able call sorting after pagination.

Comment: `withCount()` is just a convenient way to create the subquery from the `province` relationship. You can also add the subquery with raw SQL using `DB::raw()`. Joining the `provinces` table is another possible solution.

Comment: Yes, i see. Actually, my team require using pure eloquent in controller, not using query builder. Anyway, having any solution ?

Comment: Not sure I understand your differentiation in this context. Wouldn't you see the `withCount()` solution as "pure Eloquent"? I (and others) see queries starting with `User::` as "Eloquent" and queries like `DB::table('users')` as "query builder."